# Why QTimer doesn't work in a object? python PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtimer

I'm new to python and pyqt. I just figured out that QTimer need eventloop running to work.

Why doesn't this work?

```
import PyQt5.QtCore
import sys


app = PyQt5.QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print("foo"))
        self.timer.start(500)

Foo()

app.exec_()
```

This works fine on the other hand.

```
import PyQt5.QtCore
import sys


app = PyQt5.QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

timer = PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print("foo"))
timer.start(500)

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Create an instance of the class `foo = Foo()`

Comment: @S.Nick Thanks. It works fine. but still don't know why it is working, Foo() is also an instance although it is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: @S.Nick: If you turn your comment into an answer then cavalist can approve it.

Comment: @cavalist If you don't bind the Foo() instance to a variable its reference count will be zero and it will be garbage collected atuomatically during the next cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of the class foo = Foo()

```
Foo -> <class '__main__.Foo'>
foo -> <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000000002AD8A90>
```

---

```
import PyQt5.QtCore
import sys


app = PyQt5.QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print("foo"))
        self.timer.start(500)

print(f'Foo -> {Foo}')
foo = Foo()
print(f'foo -> {foo}')

app.exec_()
```